Enabling udev package in the Buildroot seems to be breaking the build
I am trying to move my buildroot from using mdev to udev. I have removed the following config parameter from the v5 build-root dev_defconfig to remove mdev:
-BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_CREATION_DYNAMIC_MDEV=y

and enabled the config required for enabling udev in the system:
+BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_CREATION_DYNAMIC_EUDEV=y

And then tried building the kernel in the following way:
make dev_defconfig
make

But this seems to be getting me into the following compilation error:
Loading RAMDisk Image
Image too large: increase CONFIG_SYS_BOOTM_LEN
Must RESET board to recover
Signature check Bad (error 1)
make[1]: *** [Makefile:817: target-post-image] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Error 2

Does anyone has any idea where should I look to fix this? Looks like the image size including the udev has gone beyond the limit. But not sure where is this set and how to increase that?

This turns out to be a problem with the gunzip size and uboot restriction on the size. The default gunzip size defined in the uboot code is the below:
(I am working with this uboot version u-boot-2021.07):
common/bootm.c
#define CONFIG_SYS_BOOTM_LEN   0x800000

which is 8MB. My gunzip size of the image was going over 27MB and hence I had to change the above size to 30MB. I achieved this through a patch which is as follows:
diff --git a/common/bootm.c b/common/bootm.c
index ea71522d..8347316f 100644
--- a/common/bootm.c
+++ b/common/bootm.c
@@ -34,8 +34,8 @@
 #include <image.h>
 
 #ifndef CONFIG_SYS_BOOTM_LEN
-/* use 8MByte as default max gunzip size */
-#define CONFIG_SYS_BOOTM_LEN   0x800000
+/* changing the default 8MByte gunzip size to ~27MB */
+#define CONFIG_SYS_BOOTM_LEN   0x1AE0000
 #endif
 
 #define MAX_CMDLINE_SIZE       SZ_4K

So the overall structure I used is the following:

Having the following package in the buildroot:
package/uboot-tools/

Having the following patch file in the buildroot:
board/xxxx/yyyy/patches/uboot-tools/0004-max-gunzip-size-increased-from-8-MByte-to-30-MByte.patch


And then building the stack doesn't throw the compilation error anymore.
